# use rest plugin with grails project

Tags: rest, grails, groovy, rest-client

i have grails application it works fine until i install [REST PLUGIN](http://grails.org/plugin/rest). After installation i try to run my application, but running failed because of the following reason.

```
| Loading Grails 2.0.3
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application.....
| Error Error executing script RunApp: loader constraint violation: 
  loader (instance of <bootloader>) previously initiated loading for a different 
  type with name "org/w3c/dom/TypeInfo" (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

**Note:** i use grails 2.0.3 and groovy 1.8.6 and eclipse spring source tool suite 2.9.1

i try `grails> run-app --stacktrace`:

```
| Loading Grails 2.0.3
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application.....
| Error Error executing script RunApp: loader constraint violation: 
  loader (instance of <bootloader>) previously initiated loading for a 
  different type with name "org/w3c/dom/TypeInfo" 
  (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire trace.)

java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader 
  (instance of <bootloader>) previously initiated loading for a different 
  type with name "org/w3c/dom/TypeInfo"

at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlClassGetDeclaredMethods
  (ReflectiveInterceptor.java:123)

at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke
  (ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)

at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure5_closure10.doCall
  (_GrailsPackage_groovy:121)

at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke
  (ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)

at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure5_closure10.doCall
  (_GrailsPackage_groovy)

at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke
  (ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)

at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod (GantMetaClass.java:133)

at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy:119)

at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke
  (ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)

at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)

at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke
  (ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)

at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)

at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_
   closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)

at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.
   jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)

at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_
   closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)

at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.
   jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)

at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)

at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)

at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)

at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.
   jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)

at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_
   closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)

at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.
   jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)

at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_
   closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)

at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.
   jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)

at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)

at _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy:61)

at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.
   jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)

at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)

at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.
   jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)

at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)

at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_
   closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)

at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.
   jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)

at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_
   closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)

at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.
   jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)

at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)

at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)

at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)

at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.
   jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)

at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_
   closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)

at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.
   jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)

at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_
   closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)

at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.
   jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)

at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processClosure(GantMetaClass.java:81)

at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.processArgument(GantMetaClass.java:95)

at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:128)

at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp.groovy:28)

at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.
   jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)

at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)

at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.
   jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)

at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)

at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_
   closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)

at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.
   jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)

at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_c
   losure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)

at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.
   jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)

at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)

at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)

at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)

at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.
   jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)

at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_
   closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)

at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.
   jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)

at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_
   closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)

at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.
   jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)

at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)

at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)

at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.
   jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)

at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)

at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.
   jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)

at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)

at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.
   jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)

at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)

at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)

at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)

at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)

at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)

at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy) 

at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.
   jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)

at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)

at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)

at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.
   jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)

at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)

at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.
   jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)

| Error Error executing script RunApp: loader constraint violation: 
  loader (instance of <bootloader>) previously initiated loading for a 
  different type with name "org/w3c/dom/TypeInfo"
```

**application.properties:**

```
#Grails Metadata file
#Mon May 21 10:44:15 EEST 2012
app.grails.version=2.0.3
app.name= my-application
app.servlet.version=2.4
app.version=0.1
plugins.ckeditor=3.4.0.1
plugins.crypto=2.0
plugins.email-confirmation=1.0.4
plugins.excel-import=0.3
plugins.filter=0.2
plugins.filterpane=0.7
plugins.gsec=1.0
plugins.hibernate=2.0.3
plugins.mail=0.9
plugins.navigation=1.1.1
plugins.p6spy=0.5
plugins.quartz=0.4.2
plugins.rest=0.7
plugins.tomcat=2.0.3
plugins.webflow=2.0.0
```

**ANY HELP?**

**Note:** i try to use [REST Client Builder Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/rest-client-builder) but i didn't know how to use it and how to send json request body. `any one know?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it is easy to use [REST Client Builder Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/rest-client-builder) just as:

```
def test (String testName, String testDescription){
    def restBuilder = new RestBuilder()
    def restRequest = restBuilder.post(url){
        contentType "application/json"
        json {
            name = testName
            description = testDescription
        }
    }
    restRequest.json
}
```

1- url: is the url that you want to post your request

2- name & description: are the names of the parameters that you will receive in the webserver that call this method

Note: don't forget to install [REST Client Builder Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/rest-client-builder) and `import grails.plugins.rest.client.RestBuilder` in the class you use it.

Comment: your answer is correct, but do you know why i can't use rest plugin

Comment: @mbayloon As Andrew Eisenberg pointed out on the [question you deleted 4 hours ago, despite his offer to help track down the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663899/error-executing-script-runapp-loader-constraint-violation), there are two things loading the class `org.w3c.dom.TypeInfo` into their respective classloaders, so you'd need to tell one of the to exclude this required package (if possible)..  Not sure how you do this though...

Comment: i know that but i google this point but i didn't find any answer, then i try danny-london answer that tell me how to use rest-client-builder plugin instead of rest plugin. if you know how, or any one know how can i solve this error please tell me

Comment: thanks `tim_yates` and thanks `Andrew Eisenberg` and thanks `danny-london`

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem (though I needed just the http-builder library and not the plugin itself). -noreloading option did not make it any better.

However, as it pointed out here http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPEXPORT-18?focusedCommentId=69307&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-69307
one can manually list in BuildConfig.groovy all modules that refer to xmlbeans and explicitly exclude xmlbeans like

```
compile (group:'org.apache.poi', name:'poi', version:'3.7') {
  excludes 'xmlbeans'
}
compile (group:'org.apache.poi', name:'poi-ooxml', version:'3.7') {
  excludes 'xmlbeans'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug in Grails. Spring loaded, the technology that enables hot reloading of classes in Grails is causing a problem with the REST Client Build plugin.

The following command should allow you to use the plugin:

> grails -noreloading run-app